# Как сделать картинки внизу страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так,чтобы пять картинок были внизу страницы,а если на одну из них нажать то высветится информация посередине экрана сверху

```
    <style>

.image_cart {
  display: block;
}

.image_cart img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.image_cart:not(.active) .description {
  display: none;
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#somedesc {
  font-size: x-large;
  text-align: center;
}
</style> 

    <script>



    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.image_cart').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active'))
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    else {
      $('.image_cart.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    $('body').css('background', 'url(file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/1.jpg )')
  });
});

</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/2.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-2" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Лев</h3>
    <p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать 250 кг.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/3.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-3" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Барс</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/4.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-4" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Тигр</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_cart">
  <img src="file:///C:/Users/naza1/Desktop/jQuery/images/5.png" descSelector="#somedesc" alt="No image" class="img-5" />
  <div class="description">
    <h3>Пума</h3>
    <p>Бла-бла-бла</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="somedesc" class="hidden">
  <p><b>Лев</b></p>Вид хищных млекопитающих, один из четырёх представителей рода пантер, относящегося к подсемейству больших кошек в составе семейства кошачьих. Наряду с тигром — самая крупная из ныне живущих кошек, масса некоторых самцов может достигать
  250 кг.</div>
```